# Where Does Form.Size Live? I'm Having Some Super Weird Problems

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, size

Every time I open my form, it defaults to 328x192.  I'll change it to 328x170, save my project, close my project, then reopen it.

All of a sudden, my form is back to 328x192 instead of the size I saved it as (328x170).

I went into my Form.Designer.cs and tried adding this line of code:

```
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 170);
```

And still, when I reopen the project, the form is at 328x192.  I don't know where this value is coming from and it's driving me crazy.  The weird part about this problem is that it seems to occur randomly, where I will get that extra margin on the bottom of my form.  I'm worried this will slip into production because even when I save it to the correct dimensions, when I reopen it, it's back to the wrong dimensions.

Needless to say, GUI errors make my work look 1000% worse no matter how things are under the hood.

Comment: MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 170);

Comment: I guess you need to check the MaximumSize property too.

Comment: To be extra clear:
Is the use case that you set the size - build the app, everything is fine. you close visual studio, open it again, build the app and the size is different??

Comment: Does your form inherit directly from Form? Or does it have another immediate parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* edit the designer-generated code.  The designer doesn't save the Size property, it isn't a good measure for the size of the form.  The height of the caption bar of the form is determined by user preference.  It saves the ClientSize property instead.  That's an important one since it determines how much room is available to controls.

It isn't otherwise obvious what made the size revert.  Could be something as simple as forgetting to check-in the changes which then lead you on the wild Size goose chase.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the size on the form from codebehind?

**EDIT** - as in:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 170);

}
```

I suspect you might be somehow changing the form size from an active designer window.
If you set the code manually after the initialization of the form the designer won't be able to affect that.

Unless someone is messing with you :)

Comment: :)
But did it help?
BTW: Hans is right - you really shouldn't edit Designer-Generated code. You have codebehind or the designer itself for that...

Answer (score 0):

The difference (of 22) could be the header. I've checked one of my WinForms projects and it has this line in the .designer.cs file:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
```

while the size being set at 300 x 300 in the properties dialog. The difference being the border and the header dimensions.

Have you got a line that sets this and if so try altering those values instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have the MinimumSize set? Or maybe the AutoSize property is set to true.  Either of these properties could cause your window to ignore the Size property in certain scenerios.

Otherwise, I think this.ClientSize is the property you need to look at in the Designer file.  These values are the size of the client area (minus the window border).